# We launched these sales campaigns "for the government" to boost the economy - differences if without "for the government"

Tags: infinitive-clauses

**Example 1**

(1)

> We launched these sales campaigns to boost the economy.

(2)

> We launched these sales campaigns **for the government** to boost the economy.

Does (1) mean the people launched the campaigns so that they would boost the economy?

Does (1) mean the people launched the campaigns so that they would contribute to the government's effort in boosting the economy?

**Example 2**

(1)

> They are playing these shows on TV to cook food correctly

(2)

> They are playing these shows on TV **for home cooks** to cook food correctly

Does (1) mean the people play the shows so that they themselves can cook food correctly?

Does (2) mean the people play the shows so that home cooks, which can be other people, can cook food correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1:**

Sentence 1 sounds like you're meaning to boost the economy of the country/state/city.

While sentence 2 means that you're contributing to the government's effort boost the economy by launching sales campaigns.

**Example 2:**

Sentence 1 here means that playing these shows on TV contributes *them* to cook food correctly, it literally means that *they* will start to cook food correctly once these shows on TV are playing.

While sentence 2 here means that the home cooks are learning to cook food correctly from these shows on TV that are playing.